# jQuery Selection only Applying to Currently Displayed Page of HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code made to highlight a table row. It works just fine for the part of the table that is displayed, but to reproduce the error do the following on my code snippet.

1. Click on the first row
2. Sort the table so that the first row is not visible
3. Click any entry on the newly sorted page
4. Resort so the first row is on top again.

The highlighted row on page one should not be highlighted anymore because of this line

`$("tr").removeClass("active1");    //remove active1 from all tr's so only`

but it seems that jQuery is not getting entries from the page 1 when you are on page 2. The same error is present through table sorting, which is what I am really concerned with, but the problem is mostly simply reproduced by going to a different page.

How do I fix this issue?

**What I Tried**

1. Using Javascript with no jQuery. I used this instead of the jQuery bits, but have the same issue.

   ```
        document.querySelectorAll('table tr').forEach((tr) => {
            tr.classList.remove('active1');
            tr.classList.remove('sortActive');
        });
   ```

`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var table = document.getElementById('data');
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        tbody.onclick = function (e) {               //bind e to only when the body of the table is clicked (<tbody>)
            e = e || window.event;                  //create event e
            
            var data = [];
            var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
            while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {       //get which "<tr>" was clicked
                target = target.parentNode;
            }
            if (target) {
                var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");    //get table data when <tr> is clicked
                //highlight row onclick
                $("tr").removeClass("sortActive");    //remove SortActive from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
                $("tr").removeClass("active1");    //remove active1 from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
                
                target.classList.toggle("active1")   //highlight clicked
                for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                    data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
                
                }
            }
    }

$('#data').DataTable( {
                dom: 'lrtip',
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],

                //see this https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns
            });
      
$("#permits th").click(function() {
            //$("#permits tr").removeClass("sortActive");    //remove SortActive from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
            $('.active1').toggleClass('sortActive')
            $("#permits tr").removeClass("active1");    //remove active1 from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
           
        });             

});
```

```css
table tr.active1 {
      
      font-weight:bold;
      //color:grey;
      background-color:#b3ffe0 !important;
    }
    
table tr.sortActive {
      
      font-weight:bold;
      background-color:#b3ffe0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="data">

  <thead>
    <tr><th>Header 1</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr> <td>Row 1 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 3 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 4</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 5</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 6</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 7</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 8</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 9</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 10</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 11</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 12</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 13</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 14</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 15</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 16</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 17</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 18</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this by change

```
$("tr").removeClass("sortActive");    
$("tr").removeClass("active1");
```

to

```
$("Data").DataTable().$("tr").removeClass("sortActive");    
$("Data").DataTable()$("tr").removeClass("active1");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var table = document.getElementById('data');
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        tbody.onclick = function (e) {               //bind e to only when the body of the table is clicked (<tbody>)
            e = e || window.event;                  //create event e
            
            var data = [];
            var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
            while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {       //get which "<tr>" was clicked
                target = target.parentNode;
            }
            if (target) {
                var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");    //get table data when <tr> is clicked
                //highlight row onclick
                $('#data').DataTable().$("tr").removeClass("sortActive");    //remove SortActive from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
                $('#data').DataTable().$("tr").removeClass("active1");    //remove active1 from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
                
                target.classList.toggle("active1")   //highlight clicked
                for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                    data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
                
                }
            }
    }

$('#data').DataTable( {
                dom: 'lrtip',
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],

                //see this https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns
            });
      
$("#permits th").click(function() {
            //$("#permits tr").removeClass("sortActive");    //remove SortActive from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
            $('.active1').toggleClass('sortActive')
            $("#permits tr").removeClass("active1");    //remove active1 from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
           
        });             

});
```

```css
table tr.active1 {
      
      font-weight:bold;
      //color:grey;
      background-color:#b3ffe0 !important;
    }
    
table tr.sortActive {
      
      font-weight:bold;
      background-color:#b3ffe0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="data">

  <thead>
    <tr><th>Header 1</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr> <td>Row 1 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 3 </td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 4</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 5</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 6</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 7</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 8</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 9</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 10</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 11</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 12</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 13</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 14</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 15</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 16</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 17</td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Row 18</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you debug when click, you can see that the line:

```
$("tr").removeClass("active1");
```

Is working ok. All tr in the table lose their active1 class. But if you stop the debugger in that moment, you also see that your table hasn't got all the rows. So, the other row's pages are not changed.

DataTable is managing the pagination. So must clear active1 in the DataTable pagination event

**Update**

Add this code to get the pagination events:

```
$('#data').on('page.dt', function () {
    // Your code
});
```

Check this page for more info: https://datatables.net/reference/event/page.

**Update 2**

Ok. I´ll give you all changes needed to do what you want:

```
$("tr").removeClass("sortActive");    //remove SortActive from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
$("tr").removeClass("active1");    //remove active1 from all tr's so only click will be highlighted
                
target.classList.toggle("active1")   //highlight clicked

// Add this to save highlight tr
$('#data').data('activeTr', $('#data .active1'));
                
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
   data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
```

Here I added a single line to save the row that you want to highlight. After paging, we need to know this row.

After your DataTable instruction, add this:

```
$('#data').on('page.dt', function () {        
    setTimeout(function () {
       $("tr").removeClass("active1");

       var activeTr = $('#data').data('activeTr');
       activeTr.addClass("active1");
  })
});
```

This occur on paging but before do the changes in the table. So, we use a setTimeout to run our code after this changes, when the table has the new rows. We simply remove all the active1 rows and add only to the save highlight row. If the highlight row isn't in the page, none will be selected.

Check running code here: https://jsfiddle.net/2cxtu8vn/

Comment: Can you explain how to add that to the DataTable pagination event?

Comment: I am trying the in the code snippet and cannot get it to work. Any chance you can show you solution working in the snippet?

Comment: Code on JS fiddle has the same issue

Comment: If I select a row in page1, go to page 2, select other row in page2 and go to page1 again, in page1 there aren't any row selected. If I go again to page2, I can see the row selected. Is not that you are looking?

Comment: Yes, when I follow you JSfiddle link I click Row 1, it highlights, then I click the sort button, then click another row. When I click the sort button now there is one row highlighted on each page, when there should only be one highlighted total. Can it be a browser issue? I am using chrome.

Comment: I didn't click the sort button. That was the problem.

Comment: I realize that I didn't include the sorting before because I thought the errors were caused by the same phenomena. I updated my question to reflect that.